# Simple JIRA DataCenter REST endpoint not working

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am trying to perform a REST endpoint with its corresponding web fragment but I am getting the error:

```
script function failed on issue: issue: SF-347, user: mouh, fieldId: __init__, file: <inline script>, edit behaviour: https://itrac-dev.eur.ad.sag/plugins/servlet/scriptrunner/admin/behaviours/edit/8, https://itrac-dev.eur.ad.sag/plugins/servlet/scriptrunner/admin/behaviours/edit/17, https://itrac-dev.eur.ad.sag/plugins/servlet/scriptrunner/admin/behaviours/edit/21
Here is my error log here below:
2022-08-16 20:39:37,512+0200 https-openssl-nio-443-exec-278 ERROR mouh 1239x60320x27 mu7qce 10.248.27.109 /rest/scriptrunner/behaviours/latest/validators.json [c.o.jira.behaviours.BehaviourManagerImpl] Script function failed on issue: issue: SF-347, user: mouh, fieldId: __init__, file: <inline script>, edit behaviour: https://itrac-dev.eur.ad.sag/plugins/servlet/scriptrunner/admin/behaviours/edit/8, https://itrac-dev.eur.ad.sag/plugins/servlet/scriptrunner/admin/behaviours/edit/17, https://itrac-dev.eur.ad.sag/plugins/servlet/scriptrunner/admin/behaviours/edit/21
2022-08-16 20:39:36,371+0200 https-openssl-nio-443-exec-278 WARN mouh 1239x60311x26 mu7qce 10.248.27.109 /browse/SF-347 [c.s.j.p.r.rest.api.MicroDashBoard] getiTracReleaseInfo for user "mouh" took 0 ms
2022-08-16 20:39:36,371+0200 https-openssl-nio-443-exec-278 WARN mouh 1239x60311x26 mu7qce 10.248.27.109 /browse/SF-347 [c.s.j.p.r.rest.api.MicroDashBoard] getiTracReleaseInfo for user "mouh" - "green" -0
2022-08-16 20:39:36,371+0200 https-openssl-nio-443-exec-278 WARN mouh 1239x60311x26 mu7qce 10.248.27.109 /browse/SF-347 [c.s.j.p.r.rest.api.MicroDashBoard] getiTracReleaseInfo for user "mouh" took 0 ms
2022-08-16 20:39:36,371+0200 https-openssl-nio-443-exec-278 WARN mouh 1239x60311x26 mu7qce 10.248.27.109 /browse/SF-347 [c.s.j.p.r.rest.api.MicroDashBoard] getiTracReleaseInfo for user "mouh" - "yellow" -0
2022-08-16 20:39:36,371+0200 https-openssl-nio-443-exec-278 WARN mouh 1239x60311x26 mu7qce 10.248.27.109 /browse/SF-347 [c.s.j.p.r.rest.api.MicroDashBoard] getiTracReleaseInfo for user "mouh" took 0 ms
2022-08-16 20:39:36,371+0200 https-openssl-nio-443-exec-278 WARN mouh 1239x60311x26 mu7qce 10.248.27.109 /browse/SF-347 [c.s.j.p.r.rest.api.MicroDashBoard] getiTracReleaseInfo for user "mouh" - "red" -0
```

I don't understand why I have this error my code is super simple. Here is the way in which I have created my web fragment:

This is a screenshot of the custom web item fragment I have created:
[image]
This is the corresponding REST endpoint I have created:
[image]

I am specifying the file MounaBulkSummary.groovy to be the one containing the code for the REST endpoint.

[image]
Here is the content of the file MounaBulkSummary.groovy

```
import groovy.transform.BaseScript

import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.CustomEndpointDelegate

import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap

import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor

import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.ScriptRunnerImpl

import com.atlassian.sal.api.ApplicationProperties

import com.atlassian.sal.api.UrlMode

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response

import org.apache.log4j.Logger

def log = Logger.warn("atlassian-jira.log")

    log.warn("MOUNA BULK")

@BaseScript CustomEndpointDelegate delegate

MounaBulkSummary(httpMethod: "GET") { MultivaluedMap queryParams ->

    log.warn("MOUNA BULK")

    def user = ComponentAccessor.jiraAuthenticationContext?.loggedInUser

    def issue = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager().getIssueObject(queryParams.getFirst("issueId") as Long)

    def baseUrl = ScriptRunnerImpl.getOsgiService(ApplicationProperties).getBaseUrl(UrlMode.ABSOLUTE)

    def redirectUrl = "https://secapps.eur.ad.sag:9888/FPIA/?iTrac=${issue.key}&reporter=${user.key}&baseURL=${baseUrl}"

    Response.temporaryRedirect(URI.create(redirectUrl)).build()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake, I needed to use call in the URL. Here is the code for the REST API:

```
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.CustomEndpointDelegate
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.transform.BaseScript
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import groovy.transform.BaseScript
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.CustomEndpointDelegate
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.ScriptRunnerImpl
import com.atlassian.sal.api.ApplicationProperties
import com.atlassian.sal.api.UrlMode
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor

@BaseScript CustomEndpointDelegate delegate
def log = Logger.getLogger("atlassian-jira.log")


long iTracSuperFeatureSummaryUpdaterIssueTypeID= 10200; 
int  iTracSuperFeatureSummaryUpdaterProjectID= 23520; 
String iTracSuperFeatureSummaryUpdaterURL=  "http://itrac-service:8080/bulksummaryupdater/bulksplitter?key=:1:&reporter=:2:";  

callMounaBulkSummary(httpMethod: "GET", groups: ["jira-administrators"]) { MultivaluedMap queryParams, String body ->
    log.warn("MOUNA BULK")
    def user = ComponentAccessor.jiraAuthenticationContext?.loggedInUser
    Issue issue = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager().getIssueObject(queryParams.getFirst("issueId") as Long)
   def project = issue.getProject()
    def baseUrl = ScriptRunnerImpl.getOsgiService(ApplicationProperties).getBaseUrl(UrlMode.ABSOLUTE)
      log.warn("MOUNA BULK "+user+" "+issue+" "+baseUrl+" "+project +" "+project.get("id"))
      iTracSuperFeatureSummaryUpdaterURL= iTracSuperFeatureSummaryUpdaterURL.replaceAll(":1:", issue.getKey())
   iTracSuperFeatureSummaryUpdaterURL= iTracSuperFeatureSummaryUpdaterURL.replaceAll(":2:",  user.getUsername())
    def projectID=project.get("id")
    int projectIDInt= projectID as int
      if(iTracSuperFeatureSummaryUpdaterProjectID== projectIDInt && iTracSuperFeatureSummaryUpdaterIssueTypeID==Long.valueOf(issue.getIssueTypeId()) ){
   
    Response.temporaryRedirect(URI.create(iTracSuperFeatureSummaryUpdaterURL)).build()
      }

}
```

Other code for as similar REST endpoint:

```
 import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.CustomEndpointDelegate
    import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
    import groovy.transform.BaseScript
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;  
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger
    import groovy.transform.BaseScript
    import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.CustomEndpointDelegate
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
    import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
    import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.ScriptRunnerImpl
    import com.atlassian.sal.api.ApplicationProperties
    import com.atlassian.sal.api.UrlMode
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response
    import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
    
    @BaseScript CustomEndpointDelegate delegate
    def log = Logger.getLogger("atlassian-jira.log")
    
    int iTracSuperFeatureSplitterIssueTypeID= 10200; 
    int iTracSuperFeatureSplitterProjectID= 23520; 
    String iTracSuperFeatureSplitterURL= "http://itrac-service:8080/featuregenerator/bulksplitter?key=:1:&reporter=:2:"; 
    
    callMounaBulkSplitter(httpMethod: "GET", groups: ["jira-administrators"]) { MultivaluedMap queryParams, String body ->
        log.warn("MOUNA BULK")
        def user = ComponentAccessor.jiraAuthenticationContext?.loggedInUser
        Issue issue = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager().getIssueObject(queryParams.getFirst("issueId") as Long)
       def project = issue.getProject()
        def baseUrl = ScriptRunnerImpl.getOsgiService(ApplicationProperties).getBaseUrl(UrlMode.ABSOLUTE)
          log.warn("MOUNA BULK "+user+" "+issue+" "+baseUrl+" "+project +" "+project.get("id"))
          iTracSuperFeatureSplitterURL= iTracSuperFeatureSplitterURL.replaceAll(":1:", issue.getKey())
       iTracSuperFeatureSplitterURL= iTracSuperFeatureSplitterURL.replaceAll(":2:", user.getUsername())
        def projectID=project.get("id")
        int projectIDInt= projectID as int
          if(iTracSuperFeatureSplitterProjectID== projectIDInt && iTracSuperFeatureSplitterIssueTypeID==Long.valueOf(issue.getIssueTypeId()) ){
       
        Response.temporaryRedirect(URI.create(iTracSuperFeatureSplitterURL)).build()
          }
    
    }
```